# Use Monolog Logger to send output to Sentry

Tags: php, logging, handler, sentry, monolog

I currently have php setup to write its error messages, exceptions, ... to stderr using Monolog and I wanted to add an additional Handler to send the output directly to Sentry.

This is what I have in PHP:

```
$monologLogger = new Logger('logger');
$streamHandler = new StreamHandler('php://stderr');

$formatter = new JsonFormatter();

$options = [
    'dsn' => 'http://KEY@URL//PROJECTID',
    'default_integrations' => false, // use Monolog to send errors
];

\Sentry\init($options);
$sentryHandler = new Handler(SentrySdk::getCurrentHub(), Logger::ERROR);

$sentryHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
$monologLogger->pushHandler($sentryHandler);

$streamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
$monologLogger->pushHandler($streamHandler);

return $monologLogger;
```

It outputs everything correctly to stderr, but I do not receive any events in sentry.
Does anyone know what might be wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Even though I copied it directly from sentry, my DSN key was wrong.

I removed the extra '/' here:

Wrong:

http://KEY@URL//PROJECTID

Correct:

http://KEY@URL/PROJECTID

Kind of a stupid mistake, but thanks for the help anyway guys.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your problem is `dsn`.
But I used the easiest way in the project
You can find a more efficient way

[see here more #sentry integrations](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/php/integrations/#capturing-errors)

```php
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('name');
$client = \Sentry\ClientBuilder::create([
    'dsn' => DSN
])->getClient();

$handler = new \Sentry\Monolog\Handler(
   new \Sentry\State\Hub($client)
);

$logger->pushHandler($handler);
$logger->info('Message', $context);
$logger->error('Message', $context);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you catch an exception you can call this to manually send it to Sentry

```
Sentry\captureException($e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `try catch` block get the exception
There after you can call the Sentry

`Sentry\captureException($e);`